# How is object equivalence determined by the CLR?

Tags: c#, oop, object, clr

In an object oriented language such as C#, how are objects of the same type with the same value differentiated by the CLR?

For example:

```
class Foo 
{
    public string name {get; set;}

    public foo(string name)
    { 
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo("Jim"); //This foo is named "Jim."
        Foo foo2 = new Foo("Jim"); //So is this one.

        bool areEqual = (foo1 == foo2); //How is the CLR determining equivalence?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many OO languages (C# included, though the behavior can be overloaded*), the `==` operator checks whether the references to each object are equivalent, not the contents of the objects.

So, for example, this sort of thing happens:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo("Jim");
// The Foo pointed to by foo1 is stored at memory location 0x47008
Foo foo2 = new Foo("Jim");
// The Foo pointed to by foo2 is stored at memory location 0x57008

bool areEqual = (foo1 == foo2);
// areEqual is false, as the comparison being made is 0x47008 == 0x57008
```

Unless explicitly overloaded, this is the behavior of all objects in C#.  A notable exception is the `string` type, which has overloaded* `==` to actually compare the contents of the strings.  A counter-example is Java, which does *not* allow operator overloading; the correct way to compare `String`s in Java is actually to use `string1.equals(string2)`.

*: *Overloaded*, and not *overridden* (important).  See Jon Skeet's comment.

Comment: Well, that's simple enough :).

Comment: Just looking at it, I imagine that's universal behavior. How would you go about overloading the == operator if you wanted to? I mean, you could easily use something like IComparable, but I'm just curious.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward: just declare a method like this `public static operator == (Foo a, Foo b) { .. logic here... }`

Comment: Slight correction: the behaviour of `==` can't be *overridden* - it can be *overloaded*. That means it's not polymorphic - if you compare two references to equal but distinct string objects, and the compile-time type is `object`, it will still return `false`.